# Find all polynomials for $p(x+1)=p(x)+3x(x+1)+1$

Tags: polynomials

> As the heading states, find all $p(x)$ for $p(x+1)=p(x)+3x(x+1)+1$ for all real $x$.

I have no idea how to approach this. Any solution or guide how to solve these kinds of questions would be appreciated!

Comment: please, could you show us your own effort?

Comment: "I have no idea how to approach this" Frankly this is hard to believe, if only you tried... But here is a hint: How would you compute $p(4)$?

Comment: Let $p(x)=\sum^n_{i=0} a_ix^i$ and see where you can get to from there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(x) = p'''(x)$. Deriving the condition $p(x+1) = p(x) + 3x(x+1)+1$ three times, we get $$p'''(x+1) = p'''(x)\implies g(x+1) = g(x).$$

Now, $g$ is still polynomial and the last line tells us that if $\alpha$ is a root of $g$, so is $\alpha \pm 1$ and hence, by induction, so is $\alpha + n$ for any integer $n$. Thus, either $g$ has no roots or infinitely many roots. The only polynomials that satisfy this are constant polynomials, i.e. $g\equiv const.$ Since $g(x) = p'''(x)$, it means that $p$ has degree $3$, i.e. $$p(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d.$$

Substitute this into the starting condition and calculate $a=1,\ b = c = 0$, and thus $$p(x) = x^3+d.$$

Conversely, any polynomial of the form $x^3 + d$ is a solution of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

For any $x\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$ p(x+1)-p(x) = 6 \binom{x+1}{2}+1 \tag{1} $$
hence by applying $\sum_{x=0}^{n}$ to both sides and exploiting the [hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity):
$$ p(n+1)-p(0) = 6\binom{n+2}{3}+(n+1) = (n+1)^3 \tag{2} $$
so $p(x) = \color{red}{x^3+C}$.